# Groovy null and isEmpty checks on child collections

Tags: groovy

I have the following user class:

```
class User {
    String username
    Set<Role> roles
}
```

In the application, I call `SecurityUtils.getUser()` to get the current logged-in user. This method returns a valid `User` instance if the user is logged in, or `null` if they are unauthenticated/anonymous:

```
User user = SecurityUtils.getUser()
```

I am trying to write a method where I need to determine if the user is logged in or not, and if they are, I need to do something special if their set of `Roles` are either empty or `null`:

```
if(user && !user.roles) {
    // Do something special
}
```

I would like to make this Groovier, so I tried:

```
if(!user?.roles) {
    // Do something special  
}
```

And this is not working. Again, the `// Do something special` should *only* execute if:

1. The `user` is non-null (authenticated); and (
2. Has a set of `Roles` that is null; or
3. Has a set of `Roles` that is empty )

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you believe `user && !user.roles` is not groovier?

Comment: Use it this way. Whatever "clever" you'll come up with will be less readable than `user && !user.roles`. Let's assume that `!user?.roles` works. How long it will take for an average developer to understand the intent of this condition?

Comment: Lol - this must literally be the first time in history that Groovy folk recommend heavier-handed syntax!

Comment: @smeeb The purpose of Groovy is not to make every sentence the smallest possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `user` is `null`, then `user?.roles` evaluates to `null`, and `!user?.roles` evaluates to `!null`, which is `true`, so this conflicts with your first condition.

If `user` is not `null`, then `user?.roles` is equivalent to `user.roles`, and in this case all conditions are met.

Conclusion: use `user && !user.roles`. And I agree with comments, this is more readable.